# How do you save rows to an array and print out in PHP using ODBC?

Tags: php, odbc

I have the following:

```
while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $result )){ <--lots of rows
    $thisResult['name'] = $myRow["name"] ;
    $thisResult['race'] = $myRow["race"] ;
    $thisResult['sex'] = $myRow["sex"];
    $thisResult['dob'] = $myRow["dob"];
}
```

I can't figure out how to print this back out.

I want to get each row and iterate through each row in the array like a datareader.  I'm not sure what to do.  I do not want to do the echo in the while.  I need to be able to print it out elsewhere.  But I don't think I've done it right here to be able to print it later.

I also tried, this, however:

```
while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $result )){ <--lots of rows
     print($thisResult[$myRow["name"]] = $myRow);
}
```

I then tried:

```
while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $result )){ <--lots of rows
    print (odbc_result($myRow,"name"));
}
```

but got an error.

Thank you for any help.

EDIT:  when I do this:

```
while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $result )){
    print ($myRow["name"]);
}
```

I get undefined index name.  I am mainly concerned with saving to an array but I have to be able to do it in the loop first.

Comment: What does an `print_r($myRow)` give you? You just  have to figure out what values are really in your array.

Comment: what happened to the other answer?  it was right! thank you wherever you went to.

Comment: If you say so, I undeleted it again ;) I was confused that `$myRow["name"]` gives you an index error, that is why I deleted my answer as I didn't think that it would work then.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declare an array before and assign the values to it:

```
$rows = array();

while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $result )){ <--lots of rows
    $rows[] = $myRow;
}
```

Then you can print it e.g. this way:

```
foreach($rows as $row) {
   foreach($row as $key => $value) {
       echo $key . ': '. $value;
   }
}
```

or however you want to.

You don't have to access and assign `$thisResult['name'] = $myRow["name"]` in your `while` loop as `$myRow` already is an array. You just copy the values which is unnecessary.

---

You say you have a lot of rows. Depending of what you really want to do with data, it might be better to put all this functionality into the while loop to avoid creating an array.

Comment: I think you mean $rows[] = $myRow;

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
$output = '';
while($myRow = odbc_fetch_array( $result )) {
    $output = $output."Your name is {$myRow["name"]} and your race is {$myRow["race"]}\n";
}

// print output later...
```